# How to access postgres database on host from within docker container?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with django project that trying to use database situated on host machine.

Now my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code.
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN export dockerhost=$(docker-machine ip)
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

networks:
  workernetwork:
  webnetwork:

services:
  static:
    volumes:
      - /static:/static
      - /media:/media
    image: alpine:latest

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "SECRET_KEY=temp_value python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python /code/manage.py migrate && /code/run_gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    volumes_from:
      - static
    env_file:
      - secrets.env
    ports:
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - webnetwork
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:${dockerhost}"
```

`DATABASES` in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'revolution',
        'USER': get_env_setting('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_env_setting('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'dockerhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

What Im doing wrong?

Thx for attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved with docker volume:

as first, create volume:

```
docker volume create --name=coredb
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  ...    
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python /code/manage.py migrate && /code/run_gunicorn.sh"
    volumes:
      - /static:/data/web/static
      - /media:/data/web/media
      - .:/code
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    volumes:
      - pgdata: /var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
    external:
      name: coredb
```

.env variables:

```
POSTGRES_DB={hidden}
POSTGRES_USER={hidden}
POSTGRES_PASSWORD={hidden}
```

Important:
You need to create database and user manually via `docker exec -it backend_db_1 bash` and following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) instructions till `Install Django within a Virtual Environment` chapter